# Cannot get Request Runtime permissions to work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am trying to get my android camera application to work on newer versions of android and have followed the developers lesson from google on "Requesting permission at runtime" rather closely but I'm still getting the error in logcat, and the app crashes when i try to open the camera. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here.
Here are the relevant methods in my code:

```
private void showPictureDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {
            "Select photo from gallery",
            "Capture photo from camera"};
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            choosePhotoFromGallary();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            checkPermissionsR();

                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    pictureDialog.show();
}
public void checkPermissionsR() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePhotoFromCamera();
        } else {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "need external storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
        }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePhotoFromCamera();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "permission was not granted to save images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Also, I don't think the problem is here, but I will include this section too in case it is.

```
private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        saveImage(thumbnail);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    RecyclerView.Adapter newImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(BingoGalleryFolder); //***************//
    recycleView.swapAdapter(newImageAdapter,false);
}

public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";

}
```

Comment: It would help if you post logcat output.

Comment: ok, I'll do so in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try requesting all the permissions at once at the start up of your application.
Like in your `MainActivity`

First in your `onCreate` method call this:

```
checkPermissions();
```

Then try calling these methods:

```
private void checkPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (!checkAllPermission())
                requestPermission(); 
        }
    }

private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]
                {
                        CAMERA,  
                        READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        //check more permissions if you want
                     ........


                }, RequestPermissionCode);
    }
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestPermissionCode:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean CameraPermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean ReadExternalStatePermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean ReadWriteStatePermission = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    //
                    .......


                    if (CameraPermission && ReadExternalStatePermission && ReadWriteStatePermission) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions acquired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "One or more permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkAllPermission() {

        int FirstPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);
        int SecondPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int ThirdPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        .....


       return FirstPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                SecondPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ThirdPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                }
```

Comment: I want to try this but i'm getting a "cannot resolve symbol" for RequestPermissionCode in requestPermission. I'm not getting the option to import anything for it, is that a variable i need to initialize?

Comment: Yes you need to define it globally.. 

such as..

`public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

In your case 1  , You are taking permission about writing external storage , you should take permission about using camera, SO first mentioned permission in your manifest like this .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and in your **checkPermissionsR()**  get this permission

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.Camera)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you and it works fine on my project.

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 124;
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 124;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public static boolean checkPermissionread(final Context context) {
            int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public static boolean checkPermissionwrite(final Context context) {
            int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public static boolean checkPermissioncamera(final Context context) {
            int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        protected ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        protected void showProgressDialog(String title,String message)
        {
           /* if(mProgressDialog!=null)
            {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }*/
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,title,message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                //Show Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,false)) {
                //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        sentToSettings = true;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else {
                //just request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,true);
            editor.commit();


        } else {
            //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.Manifest;
```

Add this line to the Activity

Answer (score -1):

Try adding permission to MANIFEST file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and in your checkPermissionsR() get this permission

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.Camera)
```